# An example of a generalized topological space which is not Baire

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $(X,\tau)$ is a pair in which $X$ is a non-empty set and $\tau \subset 2^X$ satisfies :

(1) $X,\emptyset \in \tau$,

(2) $\tau $ is closed under arbitrary unions.

Then $\tau$ is called a generalized topology and $(X,\tau)$ is called a generalized topological space.

Are generalized topological spaces (which are not topological spaces) satisfying:

$$U_1 \cap U_2 \neq \emptyset  \Rightarrow  int(U_1 \cap U_2 )\neq \emptyset , \forall  U_1 ,U_2 \in \tau$$
, Baire spaces?

Notation "$\operatorname{int}$" and definition of a Baire space are defined as the same as those in topological spaces.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Ordinary topological spaces satisfy all your properties and there are ordinary topological spaces that are not Baire space. eg. ${\bf Q}$.

Comment: @coudy Sorry, you're right. I've made a mistake. I meant generalized topological spaces which are not topological spaces.

Comment: By writing "definas as the same as those in topological spaces" you are asking us to accept on faith (or requiring us to verify) that all the various equivalent definitions of, e.g., "nowhere dense set" in a topological space, remain equivalent in the setting of generalized topological spaces. I think it would be better if you would simply include the needed definitions in your question.